# Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Discord

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the Google Sheets `QUERY` function, and I have two sheets, and am trying to query a range in one sheet using a value from another sheet.

Here is the query:

```
=query(EntireLI, "Select * where D is not null and D CONTAINS "&C43&"", false)
```

I also tried `LIKE` instead of `CONTAINS`.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: 
       Discord
```

When I change `"&C43&"` to `'Discord'`, then the function works, but I want it to grab this value dynamically, rather than hardcoding it.

I do not understand why it is using the value of the cell as the name of the column.

The broken query:

[image]

The sheet I am querying:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(EntireLI, "where D is not null and D contains '"&C43&"'", 0)
```